# Title of an anime with a certain side-story

Tags: myself-yourself

I'm looking for an anime that involved a side-story where a certain young girl (she was probably a grade-schooler and the guy was a high-schooler) liked the male main protagonist of the story. I remember that the girl confessed to the main protagonist and was dumped because (of course) of being too young and the male protagonist liked the female protagonist. I'm not sure if the girl was relatively younger than the main protagonist, but she probably was (based on my vague memory). There was a boy who was younger than the girl who had a crush on her (not really sure) and she was a bit cold to that boy, saying that she might end up just like what happened to her.

> In the end, when they grew up, the girl and the younger boy ended up together. I quite remember the scene where the younger boy was waiting on the couch and was saying something like "oneesan, hurry up". And then it revealed that it was the girl the boy (who was then a teenager) was referring to and that they were a couple.

I'm sorry for being vague but I really can't remember. As far as I can remember, the graphics are like in Special A and I guess the story was too (those kind of stories where there is a club and everything revolves around the club members liking each other etc.).

Comment: You just spoiled it for me. :)

Comment: Sounds suspiciously close to Cardcaptor Sakura, but it isn't it :P

Comment: @xjshiya I'm afraid you description is still a bit vague, do you remember anything else about the main series episodes? Like when you saw it or how long the series was?

Comment: It's very uncommon to call one's girlfriend "onee-san" in Japanese (unless it's a story with an incest element and she actually is his sister). I suspect that either they were still in a very casual relationship at that point, or you got that line wrong.

Comment: @Krazer, Yes it is vague. I don't why I can't remember what anime was it. I remember that the girl's confession to the main protagonist occurred during sunset. I think the series was 12-episode long, or 26-episode? I really don't know, I'm sorry. :(

Comment: @LoganM, hm.. I'm not sure if it was indeed "oneesan" or maybe it was "senpai"? But I'm sure that he regarded the girl like that since the girl got pissed off (like tsundere characters do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally! I remembered what it was!

The title of the anime I was searching for was **Myself; Yourself**.

The young girl was **Hinako Mochida**. The guy he liked was **Shusuke Wakatsuki**, who was one of Sana's (male protagonist) childhood friend. And she ended up with Asami's cousin.

> Hinako is ten years old at first but becomes eleven in the course of
>   the story. She is in love with Shusuke from when he saved her from
>   three bullies who took her bag and would not give it back. She seems
>   to want to learn how to be the girl he will like and asks Sana and Aoi
>   for help. Hinako has a personality comparable to Aoi's, however being
>   only in the fifth grade, she is childish as a result of her age. In
>   the last anime episode, it is shown that she is the girlfriend of
>   Asami's cousin, who is five years younger than her.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myself_;_Yourself) is where I checked if what a friend of mine suggested (that the anime I was looking for was Myself; Yourself) was right, and he is.